# script attributes prevent javascript running

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my html I have:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous">
console.log('hello');
</script>
```

and I get nothing in console, but as soon as I remove all attributes in the script tag:

```
<script>
console.log('hello');
</script>
```

I can see the output in console. Yesterday everything worked fine, but today something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both a `src` and code inside your `script`

What you should do:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
  console.log('hello');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works now! Weird, yesterday it seemed like it worked this way, but today it is not.

Comment: So....many....duplicates.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can not put code with src file.
For that you must have to write separate  include javascript file code and other javascript code like below.

```
Here you can include 3rd party javascript or jquery file like this:

    <script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And for additional javascript code you can write like this:

```
<script>
console.log('hello');
</script>
```

Comment: How is your solution different from Carsten's?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Script Not Support `Src` and Others Code in the one Script tag

The pure javascript Normally Support `console.log` and `alert()` not needed for any others library or jquery.

if you try this code here

```html
<script>
  console.log("Hello Console");
</script>
```

--- Thnk You ----